# Assigning empty strings - throws exception

Tags: objective-c

Hi there
I ran into this problem, where when i assign an empty string to a variable xcode throws an exception `[NSPlaceholderString initWithString:]: nil argument`

My scenario is

1. Make a connection to server that gives xml.

2. Am breaking up the xml and adding to the necessary variables as below

```
NSString *city_xml=[[NSString alloc] init];
NSString *state_xml=[[NSString alloc] init];
NSString *country_xml=[[NSString alloc] init];

city_xml=[TBXML valueOfAttributeNamed:@"name" forElement:city];
state_xml=[TBXML valueOfAttributeNamed:@"state_name" forElement:city];
country_xml=[TBXML valueOfAttributeNamed:@"country_name" forElement:city];
NSLog(@"%@ %@ %@",city_xml,state_xml,country_xml);

//release the strings after using them
```

When the xml returns an empty string, the said exception is raised.

What is the commonly used way of handling this exception?

I am using the following to workaround the problem...

```
if ([TBXML valueOfAttributeNamed:@"name" forElement:city]!=nil) {
    city_xml=[TBXML valueOfAttributeNamed:@"name" forElement:city];
} else {
    city_xml=@"";
}

if ([TBXML valueOfAttributeNamed:@"state_name" forElement:city]!=nil) {
    state_xml=[TBXML valueOfAttributeNamed:@"state_name" forElement:city];
} else {
    state_xml=@"";
}

if ([TBXML valueOfAttributeNamed:@"country_name" forElement:city]!=nil) {
    country_xml=[TBXML valueOfAttributeNamed:@"country_name" forElement:city];
} else {
    country_xml=@"";
}
```

But is there a proper way to handle this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that when the xml attribute doesn't have a value you're not assigning an empty string to it, you're assigning an `[NSNull null]`, which (obviously) you can't assign to an NSString. Checking for the nil value is the only way to handle it that I know of.

Comment: It's not returning `[NSNull null]`, it's returning `nil`. There's no reason you can't assign `nil` to an NSString; but what you can't do is use it in something like: `[NSString stringWithString:nil]`.

Comment: @David Why then is his original `city_xml=[TBXML valueOfAttributeNamed...` throwing that exception if `[TBXML valueOfAttributeNamed...` is `nil`?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a problem:

```
NSString *city_xml=[[NSString alloc] init];
...
city_xml=[TBXML valueOfAttributeNamed:@"name" forElement:city];
...
//release the strings after using them
```

You are allocating an NSString and storing it in `city_xml`, but then you assign a new value to `city_xml`, leaking the object that you allocated.

Then when you release `city_xml`, you are releasing an object you don't own (the object returned from `-valueOfAttributeNamed:forElement:`.

Comment: Good point on the allocating and then pointing away. A better alternative is `NSString *city_xml=[[NSString alloc] initWithString:city_xml=[TBXML valueOfAttributeNamed:@"name" forElement:city]];`

Comment: Except you still need the `nil` check: `[NSString alloc]initWithString:nil` will give you the error `-[NSPlaceholderString initWithString:]: nil argument`

Comment: Thanks, i actually fixed it right after posting this. So the code is not leaking anymore. But am still wondering how to handle those nil values without having to check each value individually.

Comment: Make a convenience method that calls `-valueOfAttributeNamed:forElement:` and returns `@""` instead of `nil`. You could define this as a category method on `TBXML`

Comment: Thanks david, that's one thing to do. I was just wondering if there was already a method or something to do this. I will choose writing a method for now.